# Sencha touch 2 implement CRUD oeration

Tags: json, jsp, rest, db2, sencha-touch-2

i am new for sencha touch. I having a problem now. I need to implement CRUD operation by using REST architectural.

But i no idea how to start it. Can anyone guild me or provide me some tutorial ? Btw i am using JSP and my database is DB2.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Sencha Touch 2.1 entrypoint is http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.

in short you have to define Ext.data.Store which proxy is Ext.data.proxy.Rest. 
Let know if you need more assistance...

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks bro .I am stuck how to implement CRUD for java and DB2 . Did you got any example?

Comment: writing the answer I presumed you have RESTFul server already created. If no... just googling 'restful server for java and db2' got reference to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1105httprestdb2/. Personally I'm basically a sencha guy, but few years ago I did work with java/jee etc and other stuff to say that this article may suite to you

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck at creating web services and you are familiar with java, you can try some tutorial on CXF or Jersey. Here is one for you:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/rest-web-service-using-cxf

After you are done with this you can start following sencha's tutorial as mentioned by Oleg or watch

www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5DLMfxDl9U